# PHP Foreach same key different value

Tags: php, foreach, associative-array

I've got 2 arrays with the same `$key`. So arrays are: `$users` and `$new`.

```
$users['user_id']=['user_name'];
$new['user_id']=['user_color'];
```

How can I `foreach` them that I could get something like this:

```
foreach (bla bla bla){
    echo '<option color="'.$new['user_color'].'" value="'.$key.'">'.$user['value'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?!

Comment: Is it even look like duplicate? jeez

Comment: How's it different from duplicate?

Comment: funny, you state `Is it even look like duplicate? jeez` and then you accept an answer that is identical to the duplicate's answer. So yeah, I would say it even look like duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular `foreach` loop which treats one array as an associative array, and just get the value corresponding to the key from the other:

```
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    echo '<option color="' . $new[$key] . '"value="' . $key . '">'. $value . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: thnx mate. FORGOT :D